# Save a linked list to file in C++

Tags: c++

I have two class:

```
class People
{
    char* Name;
    int ID;
    struct Date Birthday;
}


class Student : public People
{

    int Grace;
    int NoP;
    float *Score;
}
```

My linked list:

```
typedef struct _List
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
} List;
class Node
{
private:
    People* data;
    Node* next;
public:
    static void addelement(List &l,People *dt);
    static void readfile(List &l);
    static void writefile(List l);
};
```

I created some variables and add them to the list:

```
People* st1= new Student(...); Node::addelement(l,st1);
    People* st2= new Student(...); Node::addelement(l,st2);
```

These is two function i write to write/read file with my List:

```
void Node::writefile(List l)
{
    Node *p = l.head;
    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ("myfile.Dat","wb");
    while(p)
    {
        if (pFile!=NULL)
        {
            fwrite(p,sizeof(Node),1,pFile);
            fclose (pFile);
        }
        p=p->next;
    }
}
void Node::readfile(List &l)
{
Node *r;
FILE * pFile;
pFile=fopen("myfile.Dat","rb");
do
{
r=new Node [sizeof(Node)];
fread(r,sizeof(Node),1,pFile);
r->next=NULL;
if(l.head==NULL) l.head=l.tail=r;
else
  {
      l.tail->next=r;
      l.tail=l.tail->next;
  }
}while(!feof(pFile));
fclose(pFile);
}
```

When i read the file and save to another linked list, and i just got first line right.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You appear to close `pFile` after writing the first node.

Comment: Linked list container pointers (addresses). These pointers won't mean anything outside of the running time of your program. You dont want to store the nodes of the list you just want to store the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your read and write file functions are at the wrong level in the hierarchy.  They should be at the list level, not the node level.  If you want them at the node level then each node should have it's own file.  Try the following:

```
typedef struct _Node
{
    People* data;
    Node* next;        
} Node;

// Only pass out copies of nodes, never nodes to ensure integrity of list items.

Class CLinkedList
{
protected:
    int     m_numItems;
    Node*   m_head;
    Node*   m_tail;

public:
    CLinkedList();
    ~CLinkedList(){};

    static void readfile(char* filename = "myfile.Dat");
    static void writefile(char* filename = "myfile.Dat");

    static void addelement(People *dt);
    static void removElement(People *dt);
};

CLinkedList::CLinkedList()
{
    // Initialize the linked list class here
}

void CLinkedList::writefile(char* filename)
{
    // Iterate through list and write values
}
void CLinkedList::readfile(char* filename)
{
    // Iterate through list and read values
}

void CLinkedList::addelement(People *dt)
{
    // Add elements

    m_numItems++;
}

void CLinkedList::removeElement(People *dt)
{
    // Add elements

    // delete the element after removing it from the list

    m_numItems--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. serialize the C++ data object (here, list) before writing to file
2. deserialize the file content to C++ data object after reading the file

For simple use cases you can do it by hand. For example, a node in the list can be a comma separated list and each node data may be placed inta a new line in the file. This knowledge about file layout can be used while reading the file.

As a visualization, the file content for name, id, dob may look like

```
Alice, 90, 1999/04/01,
Bob, 20, 2000/01/04,
```

However, if the project is long term and the data structures are expected to change (which is quite normal), then it is better to use serialization/deserialization library. One good option is to use Google Protocol Buffers, see a simple example at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial